# How to satisfy multiple byte ranges when using PushStreamContent in WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to use `PushStreamContent` because of the source of my data (effectively have to concatenate blobs), but I also have to support requests for multiple byte ranges (arbitrary ranges not aligned to the stored blobs). What is not clear to me is if I can use `PushStreamContent` to generate a `multipart/byteranges` response, if each range needs to be separated in the response, and if so, how to do it, and how it relates to the chunked transfer encoding which `PushStreamContent` invokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `MultipartContent` like this:

```
public class MyRangeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        // Create a multi-part content object for the response; note that per RFC spec, subtype must be "byteranges"
        // Note that the content type of the over-all response will be "multipart/byteranges"
        // We choose to use a GUID string for the separator; it could be anything suitable.
        var multipartContent = new MultipartContent("byteranges", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));

        // Create the response object and set its content
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent) { Content = multipartContent };

        foreach (var rangeItemHeaderValue in Request.Headers.Range.Ranges)
        {
            // Create  PushStreamContent object for our current byte range...
            var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream1, content, arg3) =>
            {
                // Write to stream1

                stream1.Close();
            });

            // We need to add certain headers to each part of the response
            pushStreamContent.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(rangeItemHeaderValue.From.Value, rangeItemHeaderValue.To.Value, /* total size of the resource */);
            pushStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(/* Set a content type for each part of the response */);

            // Add the part to the multi-part content response
            multipartContent.Add(pushStreamContent);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```